# Combining Parameterlist in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to combine two `ParameterList`s in Pytorch. I've implemented the following snippet:

```
import torch

list = nn.ParameterList()
for i in sub_list_1:
    list.append(i)
for i in sub_list_2:
    list.append(i)
```

Is there any functions that takes care of this without a need to loop over each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nn.ParameterList.extend`, which works like python's built-in `list.extend`

```py
plist = nn.ParameterList()
plist.extend(sub_list_1)
plist.extend(sub_list_2)
```

Alternatively, you can use `+=` which is just an alias for `extend`

```py
plist = nn.ParameterList()
plist += sub_list_1
plist += sub_list_2
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jodag's answer, one other solution is to unwrap the lists and construct a new list with them

```
param_list = nn.ParameterList([*sub_list_1, *sub_list_2])
```